# Magento Theming Extra HTML Wrappers In list.phtml File

Tags: magento, theming

I have made a custom Magento theme by heavily customizing the base. I've made it responsive using Twitter bootstrap. On the homepage I am showing products in a **2column-right** layout.

**2column-right.phtml:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12 page">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span9"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?></div>
                <div class="span3"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right') ?></div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- ./page -->
    </div>
</div><!-- ./container -->
```

the list is shown using list.phtml:

```
<?php // Grid Mode ?>
<?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
<ul class="thumbnails">
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <li class="span3 item <?php if($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
        <div class="thumbnail clearfix">
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(260); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>"/><!--145x215-->
            </a>

            <?php
            $itemName = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name');
            $limit = ($ilimit) ? $ilimit : 23;
            $pad=' &hellip;';
            $itemName = strip_tags($itemName);
            if(strlen($itemName) > $limit) {
                $itemName = substr($itemName,0,$limit);
            }
            $itemName = $itemName.$pad;
            ?>

            <h3><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $itemName; ?></a></h3>

            <div class="price-box">
                <span><?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?></span>
            </div>

            <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-medium pull-left" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></button>
            <?php else: ?>
                <button type="button" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-medium pull-left"><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></button>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="btn btn-medium pull-right"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Nowhere in my code is there a mention of a **std** or **side-col** or **col-left** but still the output HTML is:

```
<div class="std">
    <div class="col-left side-col">
        <p class="home-callout"><span></span></p>

        <ul class="thumbnails">
            <li class="span3 item  first">
                <div class="thumbnail clearfix">
                    <a href="http://localhost:8888/index.php/sony-vaio-vgn-txn27n-b-11-1-notebook-pc.html" title="Sony VAIO VGN-TXN27N/B 11.1&quot; Notebook PC">
                        <img src="http://localhost:8888/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/260x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/s/o/sony-vaio-vgn-txn27n-b-11-1-notebook-pc.jpg" alt="Sony VAIO VGN-TXN27N/B 11.1&quot; Notebook PC">
                    </a>

                    <h3><a href="http://localhost:8888/index.php/sony-vaio-vgn-txn27n-b-11-1-notebook-pc.html" title="Sony VAIO VGN-TXN27N/B 11.1&quot; Notebook PC">Sony VAIO VGN-TXN27N/B  …</a></h3>

                    <div class="price-box">
                        <span>
                            <div class="price-box">
                                <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-27">
                                    <span class="price">Rs2,699.99</span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-medium pull-left" title="Add to Cart" onclick="setLocation('http://localhost:8888/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4ODg4L2ZsYWlyYmFnL2luZGV4LnBocC8,/product/27/')">Add to Cart</button>
                    <a href="http://localhost:8888/index.php/wishlist/index/add/product/27/" class="btn btn-medium pull-right">Add to Wishlist</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**I need to remove these extra wrappers (std, side-col & col-left). This is spoiling the layout in a few places.** I don't what files to change for this. I have googled a lot but didn't find anything. I don't completely understand the layout xmls but from what I saw it's just giving stuff to the templates.

I don't know what to do. I'm stuck. Please help.

**Also there are these extra empty tags in places just bothering me for no reason like**:

`<p class="home-callout"><span></span></p>` and another extra `<p></p>` at the bottom. Why are these here. Is there a way to remove these too? I would love it if I could.

I really appreciate all the help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you've solved it already, but for those ending up here with the same question:

The problem is caused by the WYSIWYG editor and is easily fixed. On the page that displays this div and span(s) erroneously, go to CMS -> Pages and select your page. In the contents-section of this page, turn off the editor and manually remove the divs/spans as desired.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I solved it long back, I should've answered. I forgot. My bad. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you searched the google but have you searched your codebase ?

```
grep '<div class="std">' app/design/ -rsn
```

This reveals a few places where it is defined (at least in base template)

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/description.phtml:36: <div class="std">
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml:79: <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/catalog/product/view.phtml:78: <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
```

so in order to know you just have to search the right place, why search google if the output must be generated from your codebase:

```
grep 'col-left' app/design/ -rsn
```

this will give you the place where this class is used in your templates

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml:50: <div class="col-left sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?></div>
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/3columns.phtml:51: <div class="col-left sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?></div>
app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/page/3columns.phtml:51: <div class="col-left sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?></div>
app/design/install/default/default/template/page.phtml:90: <div class="col-left side-col">
```

but in order to avoid those being added you have two choices:

1. learn the xml way and how to remove and add blocks
2. learn the css and create styling that fixes your layout without touching the DOM

Comment: As a matter of fact I did but after asking the question and did manage to get rid of the std div, but the "col-left side-col" is not to be found in any file but one:

`app/design/install/default/default/template/page.phtml:90: <div class="col-left side-col">`

I don't know how that can affect my theme. It's the install folder.

Thanks for replying!